# Converting RTF format to HTML tags

Tags: c#, html, winforms, rtf

Maybe someone can help me with the following problem.
I have a rich textbox control: RichTxtDescription.
 I fill the text like:

```
String _description = “Some text with rft tags like \\ine , \b,  \b01 etc.”;
 RichTxtDescription.Rft = @"{\rtf1\ansi " + _Description + "\\line \\line Query: \\line .}";
```

In my winform application, the richtextbox control gets filled as it should be(text with new lines, bolds etc). 
Now, I want to convert the richTxtDescription.Rft to html tags, to show it on a rtf field what only accepts html tags.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: just for clarification: You want to convert your rtf-document to a html-document and both should have the same appereance?

Comment: hi, no i want to convert (rtf) string to a (html) string. And yes, both should have same appereance

Comment: then you need to *PARSE* the whole rtf string (not as easy as it may look like), if you dont know how to start, you should look for third party libs that do the job for you.

Comment: BUT if you have the time, here is a link: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27431/Writing-Your-Own-RTF-Converter

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I used this [RTF Converter](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27431/Writing-Your-Own-RTF-Converter) yesterday :) and I am very happy about it.

- Download that project
- Compile the solution "RtfWinForms2010.sln".
- In the bin folder (same level as the solution), you will find the DLL's that you can use. Their names start with "Itenso". The one you might be interested in will be "Itenso.Rtf.Converter.Html.dll" and the ones that this DLL depends on.
- Add reference to your project and use the following snippet as starting point.

  IRtfDocument rtfDocument = RtfInterpreterTool.BuildDoc( yourRtfVariable );

  RtfHtmlConverter htmlConverter = new RtfHtmlConverter(rtfDocument);

  string html = htmlConverter.Convert();

Comment: Thanks a lot it saves my day